# Converting StringForm output to a string produces unexpected results

Tags: string-manipulation

I want to compose a string that contains newlines, so I tried the following:

```
ToString@StringForm["SomeText='`1`'\[NewLine]as well as OtherText='`2`'.", "textA", "textB"]
```

I would expect this to produce a string that looked like:

```
SomeText='textA'
as well as OtherText='textB'
```

Instead, I get a string that looks like

```
SomeText='textA'                      textB'.
                as well as OtherText='
```

Directly entering the string `"SomeText='textA'\[NewLine]as well as OtherText='textB'"` gives me the correct result.

What is going on here?

Comment: [Wait for iiit](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringTemplate.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into this problem in 2009. I submitted it to WRI technical support. This is the reply I received.

> After going through your notebook, I believe that what you observed is the
>   expected behavior of ToString. To elaborate:
>
> When you use ToString[form], ToString prints out the string in the
>   OutputForm. Further this function to put everything sequentially and
>   therefore does not recognize that ALL the strings after \n should be placed
>   in a different line. Rather it just puts the string directly associated
>   with \n\n two spaces down and then resumes printing the later strings in
>   the same line.
>
> The simplest way that you can remedy this issue is to use
>
> ```
> ToString[form,TraditionalForm]
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> ToString[form, StandardForm]
> ```
>
> both these options retain the original intended format.

Following this advice will give output that *looks* the way you want, but it may not be what you really want because it is not a simple string, but an interpretation box.

```
str = ToString[
  StringForm["SomeText='`1`'\nas well as OtherText='`2`'.", "textA", "textB"], 
  StandardForm]
```

> ```
> SomeText='textA'
> as well as OtherText='textB'.
> ```

```
str // FullForm
```

[image: fullform.png]

After receiving tech support's reply, I thought I might work around this by using `Row` instead of `StringForm`, but that didn't work. It gives the same output as you got with `StringForm` because, as the tech support reply implies, the problem lies in how `ToString` works and not with `StringForm`.

If you really want a simple string, I'm afraid you will have use *Mathematica*'s string manipulation tools to build the string from component parts.

Comment: Ah! That makes a little more sense... Thanks for the help.